# WPF ListView.CurrentChanged too fast for binding

Tags: wpf, binding, listcollectionview

My case:

- MVVM
- ListView+Details(custom UserControl)
- List bound to MV.Items (IsSynchronizedWithCurrent=true)
- Details bound to MV.Items.Current
- MV.Items.Count == 100
- about 0.2sec to read details (lazy mode)

When I hold the down arrow on the list, very strange things happen:

- list items order change
- current changes in the random order
- CPU usage drastically increments
  and eventually all hangs.

I've read some post that one should start the timer or run handler in the background, but I am not able to do that, since all the binding WPF does for me.

Is there some way to instruct the binding in my DetailsControl, to wait a while before accepting CurrentItem? 
Or should I just resign from the clean solution and write custom code in my MV to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

See my codeplex project:
http://wpfcollections.codeplex.com/

There is LazyCurrentCollection that should help.